# Processing data from a large data grab

Tags: python, database, mongodb, twitter, archive

I've downloaded a large (>75GB) data grab from archive.org containing most or all of the tweets from June 2020. The archive itself consists of 31 .tar files, each containing nested folders with the lowest level containing several compressed .json files. I need a way to access the data stored in this archive from my Python application. I would like to use MongoDB since its document-based database structure seems well suited to the type of data in this archive. What would be the best way of doing so?

Here is what the archive looks like [(you can find it here)](https://archive.org/details/archiveteam-twitter-stream-2020-06):

[image: root folder]

[image: inside folders]

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit - to be clear, I am not set on using MongoDB. I am open to other database solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is certainly not a good idea. Because you need to load the database in the RAM. Excepted if you have a cluster or so, you surely not have enough RAM to host this content.

So you may want to filter it if you still want to use mongoDB to this extent.

Comment: Is there an alternative, then, to MongoDB? Or, if I were to filter it first, how would I go about doing that programatically?